# Using Regex to look for values in Python

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I have read twitter data from the web, using json, so it is in dictionary form. I have to find the tweets where TweetID end in 300 or 700 using using Python. I understand I have to use regex, but I am not proficient with regex. Can anyone please help?

```
import re
with open("tweet37.txt", "w") as o:
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet_id = tweet['id']
        if tweet_id == re.compile(r'd*700' or 'd*300'):
            print >> o, str(tweet['id'])
```

This is not giving any error, but not matching any IDs. The output file is blank.

and this is what the IDs look like. They are in tweets dictionary in tweet['id']

```
400051062968557600
400051063002116100
400051062985330700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*str methods* could also work.

```
with open("tweet37.txt", "w") as o:
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet_id = tweet['id']
        if tweet_id.endswith('700') or tweet_id.endswith('300'):
            print >> o, str(tweet['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You spelled "compile" wrong.
2. Your Regex pattern is invalid.

This is what your Regex should be like:

```
if re.search('(?:300|700)$', tweet_id):
```

`(?:300|700)` matches either `300` or `700` and `$` matches at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks fixed the typo. I ran the code but it is not matching any ID. The output file is blank.